# Change image src without re-initiating image element

Tags: javascript, image

I am trying to render quite a large number of objects (probably about 200). Here is the code I currently have.

```js
Level={x:20,y:40,name:"Level",sprite:1,sprites:["brick.png","ground.png","question-mark-block.png"]}

function draw(self){
  SpriteRenderer=new Image();
  SpriteRenderer.src="sprites/"+self.name+"/"+self.sprites[self.sprite-1]
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(self.x,self.y);
  ctx.drawImage(SpriteRenderer,-SpriteRenderer.width/2,- 
  SpriteRenderer.height/2);
  ctx.restore()
}
```

It works fine, but re-initiating the Image element is quite resource inefficient. How do I change the src of the image without re-initiating the Image element?

Also if another object existed, e.g. an enemies object, it would also be able to call this function

Comment: What's SpriteRenderer? Where is it used? How is it used? Can't you just get it using getElementById or something and just change it's src? What have you tried that you could show us?

Comment: @AlexandreElshobokshy I have added more of the code in the question